# My S5 stock email flag due date

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, stock-email-app

My S5 stock email app flags emails for 'next week' when should be 'no date'. how to fix this?

Other email apps flag ok.
I can see this in my s5 tasks and notes and in my outlook to do.
I tried samsung support and they had no solution.
I have seen other S5 users with same issue...and have seen others without but have a slightly different 'look' to their stock email despite same software version.

Flag on the go is important for those messages you do not want to miss but no time to read on the go.. and to view using your 'to do' on desktop or mobile task manager later